# Kleopatra not showing the keys that are stored in gpg

Tags: kde, gnupg, kde-apps

[Kleopatra](https://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/kleopatra/) is not displaying the keys that are stored in gpg.
Probably I have missconfigured Kleopatra or it uses another keystore. How could I properly configure Kleopatra to "see" these keys?

They are properly imported in gpg as they are visible with

```
 gpg --list-keys
```

and

```
 gpg --list-secret-keys
```

I am on Kubuntu 17.04 (but this is probably irrelevant).